# SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime #212342

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm pretty sure there is an easy way of doing this, but I just cant figure it out. I'm trying to add a value which is stored as `varchar` to the current date.

In Oracle I'm using:

```
select employee_no 
from activities 
where EXPECTED_START > sysdate - (select value from params where name='before')
```

For SQL Server I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Is there an easy way to do this as I've tried `convert`/`dateadd` but it doesn't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
select employee_no 
from activities 
where EXPECTED_START > getdate() - (select value from params where name='before')
```

Comment: What datatype is `EXPECTED_START`?

Comment: @GarethD EXPECTED_START is datetime, and value is varchar. If i do "select current_timestamp+30" is works fine. The value i'm selecting to add on contains "30" but it throws the error.

Comment: If `EXPECTED_START` is a date-related item - ***why on earth*** is it stored as a `varchar` ?? Use the **appropriate data types** for all your data! If it's a date - store is as `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need time, too

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server will automatically convert the varchar value to datetime if required. 
You will get errors if your varchar columns have invalid character, fox example :

```
colVarchar
20140909
20150909
2013-05-05
wrong
...
???
```

As you see, the top 3 rows will be valid in the automatic conversion. 
So you need to make sure you column, which store datetime as varchar, does not contain any invalid value. 
Read more about conversion [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: select value from params where name='glob_days_before'; Result = 20

select getdate() - 20; result = 2014-05-28 10:58:32.263

    select getdate() - (select value from params where name='glob_days_before'); = "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate your problem by simply using:

```
SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + '30'
```

This is because SQL Server is trying to convert `'30'` to a date, as defined by [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190309.aspx).

Since in an expression all components must be of the same datatype, and `DATETIME` has a higher precedence that `VARCHAR`, before anything can be done the VARCHAR must be implicitly converted to a datetime, whereas what you actually want it converted to an int. So you need to do an explicit conversion:

```
SELECT  employee_no 
FROM    activities 
WHERE   EXPECTED_START > GETDATE() - (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM params WHERE name='before');
```

Alternatively you could use the `DATEADD` function, which will force conversion to an integer:

```
SELECT  employee_no 
FROM    activities 
WHERE   EXPECTED_START > DATEADD(DAY, (SELECT CONVERT(INT, value) FROM params WHERE name='before'), GETDATE());
```

Comment: Of course, thanks - I hadn't realised i didn't include the quote to make the 30 a string when trying to recreate it.

Thanks, I wasnt converting to an INT when I was trying the Convert/DateAdd originally but you've just sorted it for me. Thank you!